# python dictionary plot matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib

I got I dictionary

```
lr = {'0': 0.1354364, '1': 0.134567, '2': 0.100000}
```

and so goes on.

I try ploting a simple line graph with `key(0,1,2)` as the x axis and the value `(0.1354364,0.134567,0.100000)` as the y value

```
plt.plot(lr.keys(),lr.values())
plt.title('ID model model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.savefig('ID modelo: model accuracy.png')
plt.clf()
```

And I got this error.

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'dict_keys'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the method `keys()` of `dict` objects returns a [`dict_keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) object which is not supported by pyplot.

I would cast the `dict_keys` object into `list` to make this work:

```
plt.plot(list(lr.keys()),list(lr.values()))
```

As mentionned by @nikjohn:

> It should be mentioned that this is only required for Python 3
>   environments. Python 2.7 and the latest matplotlib version, are
>   perfectly okay with the code posted in the question.

Comment: @LucG - It should be mentioned that this is only required for Python 3 environments. Python 2.7 and the latest `matplotlib` version, are perfectly okay with the code posted in the question.